# Chrome puts everything HTML tag between HEAD and BODY into BODY

Tags: html, google-chrome

So my code goes something like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>

<header> something </header>

<body> </body>
</html>
```

and whenever I load this in chrome, chrome puts the header tag inside the body tag which is frustrating me. I tried this in Safari and the source shows to be fine, as I intended so.

Why is chrome doing this?

Comment: Why would this frustrate you? You don't seem to understand what the head and body elements actually are. Also I would be surprised if Safari treated this differently - make sure you're looking at the web inspector and not the old-school View Source.

Comment: @BoltClock because I know it's a valid html format to put something outside of the body tag, but tags are forced into the body tag. Not only for header, but also for anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that is supposed to be visible belongs in the `<body>`.  Thus Chrome is actually fixing your HTML for you. Validate your HTML code https://validator.w3.org/

Your code should look like, in order to be valid :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Some Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header> something </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it valid to not include body tags..? This happens for also divs and whatever tags so I don't get why it's getting forced into the body tag

Comment: @innhyu: You seem to be confusing tags with elements, in which case I don't blame you - many sources, including *other people on SO*, often get the two mixed up, when in actuality they are completely different things. You can leave out the body *tags* because they're optional, but it doesn't prevent a body element from being generated, and it doesn't prevent elements that need to be in the body element from being moved into the body element. But when you have explicit body *tags*, putting those elements outside them is telling the parser you want them outside the body, which is not allowed.

Comment: ah.. that makes more sense. 
I took "valid to omit" doesn't really matter where I put it..

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the input, I really appreciate it but I don't think that's the case...

Comment: @innhyu -  BoltClock is spot on. The precise definition comes in the HTML parser spec. After the `</head>` tag the tree constructor insertion mode is in the "after head" phase. It sees the `<header>` tag and follows the ["anything else" rulle](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#ref-for-parser-parse-error-164): `Insert an HTML element for a "body" start tag token with no attributes. Switch the insertion mode to "in body".  Reprocess the current token.` Hence the body element is created by the `<header>` tag then the header element is created inside it.

Comment: @alohci thanks! I never knew about the "anything else" rule. I guess I didn't know it to a point where I couldn't understand how I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

The header is meant to be seen anyway, it belongs in the body